# Necessary and Sufficient conditions for $F(a)=F[a]$? (Field Extension)

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Under what conditions is the field extension $F(a)=F[a]$?

Where $F[a]$ is the set of all polynomials $\sum c_ia^i$ (finite sum, coefficients in $F$).

I am doing revision of Galois Theory, I remember there are some conditions for this, but I can't seem to find it in the book I am reading.

---

Offhand, what I can remember is clearly we have $F[a]\subseteq F(a)$.

A trivial sufficient condition is $a\in F$, but that is hardly interesting.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Iff $\;a\;$ is algebraic over $\;F\;$ . The proof is reasonably easy: try it.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141219

Comment: @DonAntonio How to show that $a$ is algebraic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A necessary and sufficient condition is that $a$ should be algebraic over $F$ (Assuming $a$ is an element of a field $K$ which contains $F$). Short argument:

One direction follows from the fact that $a.a^{-1}=1$ and $a^{-1}\in F[a]$
The other direction is a classical theorem in field theory, which follows from the fact that 
$$F[a] \cong \frac{F[X]}{(P(X))}$$
With $P$ the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $F$. Since $P$ is irreducible, $(P(X))$ is a maximal ideal and $F[a]$ is a field.

Comment: What you call "ther other direction" is the only thing needed, since by definition $\;F(a)\;$ is fractions field of $\;F[a]\;$ , so *minimality* makes the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I see the sufficient direction now. Very nice. I am kind of missing out on the necessary condition, is it something obvious?

Comment: I think I get it: something like if $F[a]=F(a)$, so $a^{-1}=\sum c_ia^i$, implies $0=\sum c_ia^{i+1}-1$ so $a$ is algebraic.

Comment: Would love to know how to show that $a$ is algebraic

Comment: @Ilan If $\;F[a]=F(a)\;$ , then in particular there exists a (obviously non-zero) polynomial $\;t(a)\in F[a]\;$ such that $$\frac1a=t(a)\implies at(a)-1=0$$ and there you have non-zero polynomial over $\;F\;$ of whom $\;a\;$ is a root...