# Is it true that $k[\alpha,\beta]=k(\alpha,\beta)$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic over $k$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Is there a generalization to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141219/algebraic-field-extensions-why-k-alpha-k-alpha)?

Namely, if $k \subset K$ are fields
and $\alpha, \beta \in K$ are algebraic over $k$,
is it true that $k[\alpha,\beta]=k(\alpha,\beta)$?

Comment: Write $k[\alpha,\beta]=k[\alpha][\beta]$